# How to make offline status if the user close the browser without pressing logout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, browser

I have a logout button based on that i need to update user is: offline or online but many users just do not use that button and simply close the browser.

Tried as following code but it does not submit the last request to server. How to do that?

```
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {  
    //if (id>=2) {
    //  return "WARNING: Your status is call connected. If you refresh now, software will lose all the connection status.";
    //} else {
    //  return "WARNING: Your status is not connected. You can refresh.";
    //}

    $.ajax({
      type    : "GET",//POST
      dataType: 'json',
      url     : '/php/makeunavailable',
      data    : url,
      async   : true,
      beforeSend: function() {
      },
      complete: function() {
      },
      success : function(msg) {
        // do nothing but make offline
      }
    });


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something *similar* to what you're trying to accomplish in my experimental messaging subsystem.

One thing to note up front, you should have an idle timeout enforced server-side. Make the client notify the server of it's presence every `N` seconds, and treat clients that haven't pinged in `N + L` seconds as offline, where `L` represents some amount of predicted latency (on the high end to avoid copious "flapping").

On the client side, I've had better luck sending "last-minute" requests through when connection status changes indicate a failure/abort than with `onbeforeunload`. Admittedly, this may be due to some unorthodoxies in my code. But, browsers naturally kill off connections before they fully close the window or tab. And, it has the added advantage of triggering when something other than a page-close aborts a connection.  So, I've had good luck with it.

I use [XmlHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), so it looks something like this, where `r` is my request object:

```
r.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (r.readyState == 4) {
    if (r.status == 200) {
      // success logic
    } else if (r.status == 0 || r.responseText == '') {
      // assume the client aborted the connection
      issueLogoutRequest();
    } else {
      // failure logic
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>The full client-side source may or may not be helpful. (It's huge.) It's visible on [thepointless.com](http://www.thepointless.com) within the messaging subsystem if you'd like to poke around.</sup>

If you're using [WebSocket's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), I can't promise this strategy works equally well. But, I'd first try binding to `onclose` and `onerror` to see if either of those permit you trigger a last-minute `XmlHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but try using  `$(window).on` instead of `$(window).bind`. They should both work, but I've always used `$(window).on`. Also, what are you referencing with `function(e){`? My first, untested instinct would be to use:

`$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){`.

Answer (score -1):

if you use php in server just use $_SESSION because it is will be destroyed automaticlly when user close the browser. by the way where ar u defined this url `data    : url,`